# Do I need an MX record for email forwarding?

Tags: email, mx-record

I have my domain askerov.net registered with mydomain.com so that all incoming email is forwarded to my Gmail account using the email forwarding feature of mydomain.com.  Note that I don't have Google Apps for this account, just regular email.

Things worked fine for a while except for the occasional bounce here and there, then a few days ago emails started bouncing all the time.

Here's what the configuration looks like in mydomain.com:

Nameservers:

```
ns1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com
```

MX record:

```
@   -->  mx.askerov.net  (priority 30)
```

NS records:

```
askerov.net  --> ns1.yourhostingaccount.com
askerov.net  --> ns2.yourhostingaccount.com
```

CNAME records:

```
none
```

A records:

```
mx --> 66.96.142.50
mx --> 66.96.142.51
mx --> 66.96.142.52
* --> 66.96.163.135
askerov.net --> 66.96.163.135
```

The question is, if I am simply forwarding email to taskerov@gmail.com do I really need to have the MX record and the corresponding A records?  I suspect that the MX stuff is causing my email delivery problems.

**UPDATE**

*Email delivery is now working after I removed and re-added email forwarding. Not sure what effect that had on anything because the DNS settings remained unchanged as far as I can see. But at least I am now getting my email again!*

Comment: What is the message you get in the bounce?

Comment: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<tim@askerov.net>:
host m1.dnsix.com [66.11.225.137]: 550 relay not permitted

Comment: Sounds like you are either using the wrong server for your outgoing email, or need to login first.

Answer (score 6):

Your zone looks good as it is presented here.

The answer to your immediate question is yes, you need a MX record.

An MX record (literally, Mail eXchange) is a record that tells the rest of the internet which systems are willing to deal with mail destined for that domain.

For your zone, your MX record is:

```
@   -->  mx.askerov.net  (priority 30)
```

This means that the computer(s), mx.askerov.net, is(are) allegedly willing to deal with mail destined for your domain.  Without this record, the internet at large will not know where to send askerov.net messages.

You then have to have the record(s) for mx.askerov.net to be defined, and the machines sitting on those addresses are presumably the mydomain.com systems that do the email forwarding.

Note that depending on what your MX record is pointing at, you might not need A records for the MX system you are using.  For example, if you instead had your mx record pointing somewhere else, say

```
@ --> mx1.someplaceelse.local
```

...then you would not need the A record for mx1.someplaceelse.local -- it would be the responsibility of the domain managers of someplaceelse.local to publish the A record for mx1.

The answer to your real question, why are messages bouncing, depends on what the bounce message says.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My main concern was that the A records map mx.askerov.net to Google servers, which to me potentially indicates that anything sent to @askerov.net would be sent to Gmail as is, causing it to reject messages because obviously Google has no idea who tim@askerov.net is. Instead incoming mail should flow through the MyDomain servers that presumably handle the forwarding from tim@askerov.net to taskerov@gmail.com.